# Android: Network Service Discovery

Tags: android, android-service, p2p

I'm trying to make an android application that discovers other devices nearby running the same application with out using any local network.

I am a beginner in Android application development and i found this: 
http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

But how to use the information available on the link. And Can anyone suggest any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my recent Android project, which required network service discovery, I discovered that the Android NSD Api/Library was severely lacking.

I ended up using **jmdns**, which is a Java library supporting the exact same protocol.

The tutorial and example code I used is here:
http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html

Note: Jmdns requires that you end the names of the service types with a "." (e.g. "_http._tcp.local.") Since some implementations of the same protocol are not as strict, it can be easily overlooked.